# How to integrate streaming graph from plotly.js to my web application?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

If I embedded normal graph from plotly.js in my web application its working fine where as for streaming graph I am getting nothing to my web page.
If I create any graph,Plotly.js produce some embedded code (iframe/div).I just copy the code within (div/iframe) which they produce.For the streaming graph, i am getting nothing.so is there any other way to do that?

Comment: can anyone give the solution of the above question?or is there any other way to do that?